How do I name points on a shapefile layer?
I have a shapefile layer with a bunch of points placed on a map. I would like to name each point "R01" "R02" and so on. I know how to give each point a numerical value that I can display, but I was wondering if there was a way to do the same thing but with letters.

Labels are required for Google Earth - easier to label shapefile in QGIS and export to KMZ. (shapefiles have limited capabilities in Google Earth)

Simple shapefile (point) created

Add column (label)
Add Attributes (R01,R02)
Export to KMZ (Google Earth) with labels
option.

Shapefiles are limited (no annotation) labels points is the only way.

